# Accessing interfaceof model service in model entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

Can i access model service through model entity by using  interface of  model service.

I know that we can access entity from model service, but vice versa though model service interface is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

[You can](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern.aspx). It's certainly better than writing more procedural code - working with entities instead of letting them to work themselves.

But I agree with [Szymon Pobiega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289060/szymon-pobiega) on this:

> My own rule of thumb is use Domain Events (as desscribed by Udi) as a preferred way of IoC when interaction can be made one-way. If it can't, I use double dispatch.

Comment: But double dispatch is something different where u pass domain object into the implementation of your service. Can I inject IDomainService into the constructor of domain object and call methods of that service .For eg- : Interface ICalculate {public decimal Add(int num1, int num2);} Now , Class Advertiser { public Advertiser(ICalculate ob){} public void PerformOperation (){ob.calculate();} }